# The %[width]d formatter syntax creates a pyramid in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, string, eclipse, formatting

Using JDK 17 (Java-SE 17) This is my code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class TextBlock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bulletIt = "Print a Bulleted List:\n" +
                        "\t\u2022 First Point\n" +
                        "\t\t\u2022 Sub Point";
        System.out.println(bulletIt);
        
        System.out.println();
        
        String textBlock = """
                        Print a Bulleted List:
                            \u2022 First Point
                                \u2022 Sub Point""";
        
        System.out.println(textBlock);
        
        System.out.println();
        
        int age = 35;
        // .printf works the same as .format
        System.out.printf("Your age is %d%n", age);
        
        int yearOfBirth = LocalDate.now().getYear() - age;
        System.out.format("Age = %d. Birth year = %d%n", age, yearOfBirth);
        
        //System.out.printf("Your age is %f%n", (float) age);
        System.out.printf("Your age is %.2f%n", (float) age);
        
        for(int  i = 1; i <= 100_000; i *= 10) {
            System.out.format("%6d" + "\n", i);
        }
    }

}
```

Left out package name. Currently just learning about String formatting. The for loop at the end of my code prints this out in the console:

[image]

From the tutorial everything should superficially be right-aligned, but for some reason my Eclipse IDE decides to only use half of the width I defined for my conversion. Any help? I want to use the .printf more in my code and not being able to right-align text would be a serious blow. Or is this just one of the horrible tradeoffs of using Eclipse?

I tried doubling the width to 12 but again, only half of the width is being used in each conversion. I used repl.it to make sure it was a compiler issue and yea it is. Eclipse for some reason wants to be different from the crowd. Stupid Eclipse.

Comment: The output looks fine to me. What you might be experiencing is a matter of the font being used by the Eclipse "terminal window", i.e. it's most likely not a monospaced font and thus the space character is narrower than the digits. Have a look here on how to change the font: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm - If you're running this from your command line directly then Eclipse isn't even involved but your OS terminal settings are.

Comment: Btw, "only half of the width is being used in each conversion" is wrong. The conversion you're referring to is number/object to text conversion which results in a string of characters. The width influences the _number_ of characters being used and since characters can't be split the entire width will be used. This means `"%3d"` will turn `1` into the string `"  1"` (which in turn is the array `[' ', ' ', '1']`).

Comment: That was it. Thanks a ton man, for real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the font from Ariel to a monospaced font of my choice using instructions from [here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-consoleAppearance.htm); thanks to Thomas.

Edit: Gotta wait 2 days to accept my own answer as the solution